# How to pass brandID on the PHP SOAP API

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to tag envelopes with a brandID property per the docs, but the PHP API we're using doesn't appear to support it. The envelope class doesn't even contain a brandID property:

I'd rather not update the API code to include it (upgradability concerns). Is this a limitation of the PHP API we're using?

Here is the envelope class from APIService.php:

`class Envelope {
  public $TransactionID; // string
  public $Asynchronous; // boolean
  public $AccountId; // string
  public $Documents; // ArrayOfDocument
  public $Recipients; // ArrayOfRecipient
  public $Tabs; // ArrayOfTab
  public $Subject; // string
  public $EmailBlurb; // string
  public $SigningLocation; // SigningLocationCode
  public $CustomFields; // ArrayOfCustomField
  public $VaultingOptions; // VaultingOptions
  public $AutoNavigation; // boolean
  public $EnvelopeIdStamping; // boolean
  public $AuthoritativeCopy; // boolean
  public $Notification; // Notification
  public $EnvelopeAttachment; // ArrayOfAttachment
  public $EnforceSignerVisibility; // boolean
  public $EnableWetSign; // boolean
  public $AllowMarkup; // boolean
  public $EventNotification; // EventNotification
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is not an API, it's just one of the many languages that support web service calls that allow you to interface with DocuSign's **SOAP** or **REST** APIs.  It looks like you are using the older SOAP API... back in August 2013 the code samples were updated to include the `brandId` so you should refer to those.

More specifically, I'm referring to the SOAP SDK up on GitHub (which contains samples in PHP, C#, Java, and Salesforce (Apex)):

https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK

If you look at the PHP code snippets folder and look at the APIService.php file you'll see the updated fields at the bottom of the Envelope class definition...

```
class Envelope {
    public $TransactionID; // string
    public $Asynchronous; // boolean
    public $AccountId; // string
    public $Documents; // ArrayOfDocument
    public $Recipients; // ArrayOfRecipient
    public $Tabs; // ArrayOfTab
    public $Subject; // string
    public $EmailBlurb; // string
    public $SigningLocation; // SigningLocationCode
    public $CustomFields; // ArrayOfCustomField
    public $VaultingOptions; // VaultingOptions
    public $AutoNavigation; // boolean
    public $EnvelopeIdStamping; // boolean
    public $AuthoritativeCopy; // boolean
    public $Notification; // Notification
    public $EnvelopeAttachment; // ArrayOfAttachment
    public $EnforceSignerVisibility; // boolean
    public $EnableWetSign; // boolean
    public $AllowMarkup; // boolean
    public $EventNotification; // EventNotification

    public $AllowReassign;  //boolean
    public $BrandId;    //string
    public $BrandLock;  //boolean
    public $Accessibility;  //string
    public $MessageLock;    //boolean     
}
```